# How do you only load necessary parts of angular app based on user permissions/role?

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I am currently in the research process of building my first application in angular2 and I have a question on how to restrict the client side javascript/content that a user will see based on the permissions they have in the application.

My application will have numerous permissions that will restrict users from seeing certain pages, along with the ability to do certain actions on a page.  For a simplistic perspective, think of a configuration area for the tool/application that only someone with admin permission would be able to access.  A non-privileged user would only see the main menu items and not the "Site Settings" which leads to the admin area and therefore hopefully none of the templates/components that encompass said area.

I came across this link (http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/12/30/angular2-router-dynamic-route-config-definition-creation/) and think this might be what I need, but was hoping for other people's thoughts who are more familiar with angular and other SPA type client-side javascript frameworks.

**How do you setup an angular2 application so that only applicable templates and components are downloaded to the client based on the user's permissions?  Does all of this get thrown out the window once you use a process that combines all the angular files to limit the number of js files the client browser needs to load?**  I realize the importance of securing the middle tier API, but don't see the point of having clients download a bunch of data/templates that they will never be able to access.  Initial loads should be as fast as possible.

Comment: you also can use `*ngIf` for the same

Comment: May be this link will help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3H_YqMITSi0 This is written in angular 1 but should work the same for angular 2 also.

Comment: @PardeepJain I know ngIf will prevent the elements from even being in the DOM on the client.  However, all of the code and logic to run those sections would still be included in the javascript that is downloaded initially.